# Am I calling this API correctly from frontend js HaveIbeenpwned API

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, http-status-code-401

I am trying to call this API. I have to pass a hibp-api-key which is the key and an user-agent as headers. As I am calling from frontend I got cors error; I fixed that by using an free proxy server that fixes cors namely https://corsproxy.io/?, but when I run this code it says 401 that hibp-api-key is not present although I have included it at the headers. Here is my code:

```
var aj=""
const url = 'https://corsproxy.io/?' + encodeURIComponent('https://haveibeenpwned.com/api/v3/breachedaccount/test%40gmail.com');

$.ajax({ 
   type : "GET", 
   url : url, 
   headers: { 'hibp-api-key': 'key', 'user-agent': 'checking if user is breacehd with website '},
   success : function(result) { 
        aj=result
        console.log(aj)
   }, 
   error : function(result) { 
        console.log("eri")
   } 
 }); 
console.log(aj)
```

I expected a JSON result from the get API but got a 401 error. I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: You don't need cors proxy. Why are you using it?

Comment: Does that CORS proxy forward the headers?  The error suggests it does not.

Comment: How would I be able to check if the proxy does forward headers and are there any free proxy servers that you know of that do support headers

Comment: @BloxGuard: I guess you'd have to check with the documentation/support for that service.  Alternatively, you could expose a server that you control and use that service to make a connection to your own server, testing if headers are included in the request that your server receives.  As for recommending other services, that's off-topic for this community.

Comment: From the API doc: [_CORS is only supported for non-authenticated APIs._](https://haveibeenpwned.com/API/v3#CORS)